# How to know which button triggered the modal on pressing close button on modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</button>      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">

    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="saveHTML(this)" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

```
function saveHTML() {
    //code

}
```

I have modal html and along with that I have few button, all of which can trigger the button because the data-target and data-toggle attribute is set. But on clicking the close button inside the modal how can i figure out which button triggered the modal. The buttons that trigger the modal dont have a unique id because i have to make the code dynamic. So have to use 'this' operator.

Comment: Don't attach JS handlers inline; separate presentation from content. Attach them using proper Javascript instead and then check `event.target` to identify the origin element.

Comment: is there many modals in same page ?

Comment: no, just one. but many buttons that can trigger the modal but they cannot have a unique id or class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use js to open the modal and store the target element. You can open the below link and test it.

https://jsbin.com/nejukidopi/1/edit?html,js,output

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  var currentBtn;
  
  $('.my-edit-btn').on('click', function(event){
    currentBtn = event.target;
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
  
  window.saveHTML = function(){
    alert($(currentBtn).text());
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<body>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success my-edit-btn">Edit 1</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success my-edit-btn">Edit 2</button>      
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
         <!-- Modal content-->
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="saveHTML()" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple solution 1:
you can add custom class to know which button is clicked, this solution will add the class on the button itself and then later you can identify this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("pressed");
    });
});
```

simple solution 2:
on button clicked attach the function right away

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        function .....//logic
    });
});
```

I have many solutions too but for that i need to see for what purpose you want this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to buttons so that you will be sure which button appears to close  modal

In My case:

Button:

```
<button class="close" id="close_modal_button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Listener:

```
$('#close_modal_button').on('click', function(){
$(event).val(String(event.dataset['value']));
});
```